# How to Identify the Error OR Reason for Empty Response Body from "Hubspot" to my own application

Tags: api, coldfusion, hubspot

I am new to using Hubspot and am trying to use "Hubspot Integration" for my Application. In the Hubspot Application, they used their own URL to return a response using Webhooks. It returns the response "ok":

- Sample URL: http://requestb.in/1crqrit1

However, if I put in my application URL, it returns no response: only an empty string.

- My Sample URL : https://XXX/user_testinbound.cfm?dsname=XXX

To get the response body I used this code:

```
<cfparam name="dsname" default="XXX" />
<cfquery name="privlog" datasource="#dsname#">
    INSERT INTO tempmessage(message)
    VALUES('Hubspot inbound : #GetHttpRequestData().Content#' )
</cfquery>
```

However, it returns an empty response. In the message column it only shows the hard coded value "Hubspot inbound :". It doesn't contain any response body.

```
Message        Hubspot inbound :          
Creationdate   2016-11-08 04:25:20.857
```

If I use the sample Application "Requestmaker" site to POST my URL, it returns a non empty response.  Any ideas what might be the issue?

Comment: When in doubt, look at your data.  `cfdump` is a better method than query results.

Comment: @DanBracuk Sir If I put cfdump it shows content as [Empty String] only.So My URL doesn't hits the external application or any other issues.

Comment: @jsaonboo You can check whether the response having data or not on before insert the message. Maybe the API credentials need to be check which is using for your application.

Comment: @SathishChelladurai response having data when I checked through 'HubSpot' requestbin Application.